# Is this a matrix notation of standard error?

Tags: probability, matrices

What is the matrix notation of the standard error? A friend is referencing the standard error as:

$$SE^2=(XX^T)^{-1}\sigma^2$$

$$\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n-p}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |\hat{y_i}-y_i|$$

Where $X$ is matrix of independent values, $\hat{y}$ is observed values, $y$ is model estimates, $p$ is degrees of freedom, and $n$ is the number of observed values. Is this correct? If so, why?

I think $SE = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$, and that is not the same number as the above equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the linear regression problem $\hat{y} = X\beta + \epsilon$, where $\beta$ is a vector of unknown parameters and $\epsilon$ is a vector of i.i.d random disturbances satisfying $E\{\epsilon | X\} = 0$ and $E\{\epsilon\epsilon^T|X\} = \sigma^2 I$. Suppose that ordinary least squares estimator is applied to estimate $\beta$, thus $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T\hat{y}$.

Variance of the estimator, $V = E\{(\hat{\beta}-\beta)(\hat{\beta}-\beta)^T\}$, is given by
$$V = (X^TX)^{-1}\sigma^2 \; \; \; \; (1)$$
where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $\epsilon$. If $\sigma$ is known, than this is final form of the variance matrix $V$. However usually $\sigma$ is unknown and must be estimated. Unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ is given by
$$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{(\hat{y}-y)(\hat{y}-y)^T}{n - k} = \frac{1}{n - k}\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{y}_i-y_i)^2 \; \; \; \; (2)$$
where $n$ is number of observations and $k$ is number of parameters (length of the vector $\beta$). Thus, unbiased estimator of $V$ is given by
$$\hat{V} = (X^TX)^{-1}\hat{\sigma}^2$$

You may also use biased estimator of $\sigma$ like
$$\hat{\sigma}^2_B = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{y}_i-y_i)^2 \; \; \; (3)$$
This estimator is consistent since if $n\rightarrow \infty$, then $\hat{\sigma}^2_B \rightarrow \hat{\sigma}^2$. Thus $\hat{\sigma}^2_B$ is acceptable, but the estimator $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is better, especially if $n$ is small.

Observe, that
$$\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T(X\beta + \epsilon) = (X^TX)^{-1}(X^TX)\beta + (X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon = \beta + (X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon$$
and
$$\hat{\epsilon} = \hat{y}_i-y_i = \hat{y}_i-X\hat{\beta} = X\beta - X\hat{\beta}+ \epsilon = [I - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T]\epsilon \; \; \; (4)$$
which clearly shows, that residuals $\hat{\epsilon}$ are biased estimator of unknown disturbance $\epsilon$. Thus, using a simple formula (3) to estimate variance of $\epsilon$, must lead to biased estimator of $\sigma^2$.

Unbiased estimator (2) is derived from the relation (4) after quite complex algebraic manipulations. Details on derivation of (1) and (2) can be found in Greene, William H. Econometric analysis. Pearson Education India, 2003.